Angular Build Failure Issue
Angular Build getting failed with below issues
`√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial chunk files   | Names         |  Raw size
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 531.96 kB |
scripts.js            | scripts       | 282.56 kB |
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 228.53 kB |
vendor.js             | vendor        | 227.83 kB |
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.52 kB |
main.js               | main          | 876 bytes |

                      | Initial total |   1.25 MB

Build at: 2024-05-16T10:20:58.313Z - Hash: 1f386b80c55bca7b - Time: 42309ms

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
`

tsconfig.app.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

tsconfig.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}

tsconfig.spec.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

Package.json
{
  "name": "webaccess-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^17.3.7",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "echarts": "^5.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^8.0.0",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.9.3",
    "ng-sidebar": "^9.4.3",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^25.3.2",
    "ngx-smart-popover": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "quill": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "xng-breadcrumb": "^11.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.18",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.30",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2"
  }
}


Have tried the below thing to build/run the application locally

We've migrated the application from angular 14 to 17.
While trying to build the application we got this error.

Some one please review these error statements and config. details.
Help us understand our problem and the solution to it.

Could you try this, inside polyfills.ts, keep only
 import "zone.js"

comment out all the other lines!
Delete the .angular folder if present
Run the below command
npm cache clean --force

If needed delete node_modules and package-lock.json, if done, then do an npm run install
Then try running the build!

Thanks for your reply, I Have tried this and it also didn't work as expected

@AjithKumar One of the imports is causing infinite loop, try commenting the imports or modules one by one until you find the problematic one!
